# NServiceBus hosted within asp.net web api project stops handling messages after a while

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nservicebus

We have successfully started an asp.net web api site up and within its start up functionality it starts an nservicebus endpoint.

This works find for a period of time sending and receiving messages but after a while the bus will send messages but it fails to handle any messages back.  We have set the idle timeout of the app pool to 0 and it makes no difference.  Recycling the app pool fixes the issue but this is not a proper fix.

The code we are using to start the endpoint is:

```
// Register the bus
        var bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .DefineEndpointName("Web.Trading")
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .Log4Net()
            .UseTransport<SqlServer>()
            .UseNHibernateSubscriptionPersister()
            .UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister()
            .UseNHibernateSagaPersister()
            .IsTransactional(false)
            .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .RunHandlersUnderIncomingPrincipal(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

Now I have seen this article: http://docs.particular.net/servicepulse/troubleshooting#causes-and-solutions but this isnt the same because even when we are on the site it is able to send but it is not handling new messages back.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does it consistently run for X minutes before it stops processing, or is it variable?  What's in the NSB log?

Comment: Also, you might add logging in the app_end event to determine whether an app pool shutdown is actually happening, or it's something else.

Comment: You might need to look at using OWIN to host the bus.

Comment: The default behavior for the bus is to stop the receiving threads when connectivity to sqlserver is lost for more than 2 minutes. Could that be the case? If this is the case there could be fatal errors in your logfile. Can you check that?

Comment: Are you using callbacks. Can you update the question with a typical usage of callbacks in your controllers?

Comment: We do a bus.reply but this is handled by a normal IHandleMessages class. What happens is that initially after an app pool recycle, the handlers all work for IEvent messages and IMessage messages, but then after a short while, sending a message will work but it will not call the handle class or pick up messages from the queue